# Dynamically create COM visible interface

Tags: c#, com, dispatch

Sorry if this is a poor title. OPOS uses a dual dispatch COM interface to pass events between the service object and control object. In my library that I'm making I have 2 base OPOS Service Objects. One is for MSR and the other is Pinpad. When OPOS uses OpenService the 3rd parameter is a object (which really is just an instance of the dual dispatch COM interface).

FYI this is the MSR interface

```
[ComImport, Guid("CCB91121-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface COPOSMSR : Base.COPOS
{
    [Description("method SOData")]
    void SOData([In] int Status);

    [Description("method SODirectIO")]
    void SODirectIO([In] int EventNumber, [In, Out] ref int pData, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref string pString);

    [Description("method SOError")]
    void SOError([In] int ResultCode, [In] int ResultCodeExtended, [In] int ErrorLocus, [In, Out] ref int pErrorResponse);

    [Description("method SOOutputComplete")]
    void SOOutputComplete([In] int OutputID);

    [Description("method SOStatusUpdate")]
    void SOStatusUpdate([In] int Data);

    [Description("method SOProcessID")]
    void SOProcessID([Out] out int pProcessID);
}
```

and this is the pinpad interface

```
[ComImport, Guid("CCB91131-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface COPOSPINPAD : Base.COPOS
{
    [Description("method SOData")]
    void SOData([In] int Status);

    [Description("method SODirectIO")]
    void SODirectIO([In] int EventNumber, [In, Out] ref int pData, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref string pString);

    [Description("method SOError")]
    void SOError([In] int ResultCode, [In] int ResultCodeExtended, [In] int ErrorLocus, [In, Out] ref int pErrorResponse);

    [Description("method SOOutputComplete")]
    void SOOutputComplete([In] int OutputID);

    [Description("method SOStatusUpdate")]
    void SOStatusUpdate([In] int Data);

    [Description("method SOProcessID")]
    void SOProcessID([Out] out int pProcessID);
}
```

as you can see the 2 are almost identical (in terms of the interface they are identical) they only differ in the Guid. So I thought hey i know.. how about i move those twin methods to a COPOS interface and make it DualDispatch... that failed to compile. So then I thought, ok how about I make the interface by using the CLSID since I know what those are. But I couldn't figure out how to set a object by using the activator (which I believe is how I need to do it)

Now to come down to why it is so important. I have a OPOSBase abstract class that (among other things) is responsible for firing events. Firing events is the same concept for all devices. I started off with only 1 device, a MSR device. When I added support for a pinpad device I decided it would be good to move all common properties, methods, and events to said OPOSBase class as outlined in the UPOS spec in chapter 1. So now I had this

```
[ComImport, Guid("CCB91131-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface COPOSPINPAD : Base.COPOS
{
}
[ComImport, Guid("CCB91121-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface COPOSMSR : Base.COPOS
{
}
public interface COPOS
{
    [Description("method SOData")]
    void SOData([In] int Status);

    [Description("method SODirectIO")]
    void SODirectIO([In] int EventNumber, [In, Out] ref int pData, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref string pString);

    [Description("method SOError")]
    void SOError([In] int ResultCode, [In] int ResultCodeExtended, [In] int ErrorLocus, [In, Out] ref int pErrorResponse);

    [Description("method SOOutputComplete")]
    void SOOutputComplete([In] int OutputID);

    [Description("method SOStatusUpdate")]
    void SOStatusUpdate([In] int Data);

    [Description("method SOProcessID")]
    void SOProcessID([Out] out int pProcessID);
}
```

In my OPOSBase I have a protected field called controlObject of type `COPOS`. OPOSBase has a abstract method called `SetControlObject(object dispatchObject)` and in MSRBase i do this `this.controlObject = (COPOSMSR)dispatchObject` and similarly in PinpadBase I do this `this.controlObject = (COPOSPinpad)dispatchObject`

this alows me to put in my OPOSBase all the "Fire___Event" methods. and to fire say a data event it would look like this

```
    public virtual void FireDataEvent(OPOSDataEvent oposEvent)
    {
        lock (methodLocker)
        {
            PreFireDataEvent(oposEvent);
            logger.TraceStart();
            oposEvent.LoadInputProperties(this);

            this.DataEventEnabled = false;
            controlObject.SOData(oposEvent.Status);
            logger.TraceEnd();
            PostFireDataEvent(oposEvent);
        }
    }
```

however with the code outlined above it blows up on `controlObject.SOData(oposEvent.Status);` (sorry don't have the error handy, but it had something to do with the GUID). As a test I moved the GUID and interface type to COPOS and now my DataEvent worked again. I really REALLY want to be able to keep the fire events in OPOSBase since that would keep my code base smaller and easier to manage (as it is, it is getting rather large)

so how can I acheive what i'm after?

Comment: This starting going wrong very early, made worse with more mistakes.  The name of a COM interface is irrelevant, it gets compiled away and plays no role at runtime.  Only the [Guid] matters.  So these two interfaces are actually just one interface.  Just keep one of them, which one you pick does not matter.  Stops you from making the other mistakes you made.

Comment: @HansPassant when I try to fire a MSR event using the Pinpad GUID for COPOS it crashes. I can't just keep one, I have to have both.

Comment: Having a `COPOS` instance means nothing in terms of COM, so you probably just have a pointer to `IUnknown`, which doesn't have those extra methods.  This gets more noticeable with objects from other apartments, as the proxy only allocates enough v-table space for the its methods.  Meaning, you can't have what you want, at some point you have to cast your object back to the necessary interface to call its methods.